# Template not being found when injected dynamically

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-templates

The HTML below is injected into my site on an ajax call, but the template is not being picked up.  Is there something I need to do to register it?

> Unable to parse binding attribute. Message:
>     ReferenceError: `answerTmpl` is not defined;
>   Attribute value: `template: { name: answerTmpl, foreach: answers }`

Dynamic HTML:

```html
<script id="answerTmpl" type="text/html">
    <div>
      <span></span>  <input type="checkbox" name="Answer" />
    </div>
</script>

<div id="answers" data-bind="template: { name: answerTmpl, foreach: answers }"></div>
```

Corresponding JS:

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(document.getElementById('answers'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your template name in quotes, so name: 'answerTmpl'

Comment: Thank you for the second set of eyes.

Comment: Yes, very easy to miss that if you have been looking at it over and over again